# How do pick up nearby items only?

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to build an inventory system to pick up items depending on arrays. But the problem is when I pick up an item, all other items are picked up together.  I want to collect each item alone.

THE CODE IS BELOW:

```
public class EquipItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] Items;
    public Transform []CollectedItems;
    public RawImage[] ItemImages;
    public string [] names;
    public GameObject PicUp_TXT, Drop_TXT;
    bool disabledItem = false;
    public bool ItemCllected;
    float Timer , MaxTimer = 9;
    int counter = 0;

    enum tool { Pilers, ScrewDriver, Wrench, Cutter };

    void Start()
    {
        foreach(GameObject Item in Items)
        {
            Item.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
        }

        foreach(RawImage ItemImage in ItemImages)
        {
           ItemImage.enabled = false;
        }

        PicUp_TXT.SetActive(false);
        Drop_TXT.SetActive(false);
        ItemCllected = false;
        Timer = 0;
    }


   
    public void EquipedItem()
    {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < CollectedItems.Length; i++)
         {
                
                    Items[i].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
                    Items[i].transform.position = CollectedItems[i].transform.position;
                    Items[i].transform.rotation = CollectedItems[i].transform.rotation;
                    Items[i].GetComponent<MeshCollider>().enabled = false;
                    Items[i].transform.SetParent(CollectedItems[i]);
                    ItemImages[i].enabled = true;
                }
      

        ItemCllected = true;
    }



    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        //Picup Item
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Tools")
        {
            //if (Item)
                PicUp_TXT.SetActive(true);
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
            {
                EquipedItem();

                //CollectedItem.gameObject.SetActive(false);

            }
            if (ItemCllected)
            {
                PicUp_TXT.SetActive(false);
                Drop_TXT.SetActive(true);
            }
        }

        //Drop Item
        Timer = Timer + Time.deltaTime;

        if (Timer >= MaxTimer)
        {
            Drop_TXT.SetActive(false);
        }

    }

    private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        PicUp_TXT.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Any suggestions, please?

Comment: Your OnTriggerStay is not using the element you select, instead it just calls the method of EquipedItem DropItem and from there you go over all the items you have. Instead you want to work with just the one that you triggered

Comment: You said you want to "drop and pick up each item separately", but you didn't tell us what behavior exactly you want when there are multiple items that could be picked up or dropped. How do you want the game to decide which one to drop or pick up?

Comment: @Zibelas I am a very beginner in unity and I don't know how to do that. Please if you can modify the code better do it.

Comment: @Philipp I should pick up an item when I become close to it. In my code when I go to an item and press E all items are picked up.

Comment: It seems like your question is about two different problems that seem related but are actually very different: picking up items and dropping items. Stack Exchange question should always be about one problem at a time. You seem to be more interested in picking up than in dropping, so I think we should focus on that.

Comment: I edited your question to focus on the picking up problem for now. Feel free to ask a separate question about the dropping problem.

Comment: @Philipp the problem is one because when I pick it up I also want to drop it.

Comment: No, it's not one problem, it's two different problems. Trust me with that. You will see when you see and understand the solutions to the two problems.

Comment: @Philipp thank you very much it works now. I asked about the drop items I hope you can answer me soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you currently do, is that you check if the player is in *any* collider with the tag "Tools", and if so, you use a `for` loop to go through the whole array of possible tools and set each one to the picked up state.

What you need to do is:

1. find out which tool is represented by the collider the player is in
2. use that information to pick the right tool to pick up

So first, how can we find out which tool is represented by the collider? One solution would be to add a component that contains this information and add it to those objects. Let's call it `ToolPickup`. All this component does is hold the information which tool is controlled by this collider. And because you are using  arrays to address the tools, we can use the array index for that:

```
public class ToolPickup : MonoBehaviour {
    public int toolIndex;
}
```

Attach this component to each "tool" in the world and set the "Tool Index" in the inspector to the array index of the tool it represents.

Now, in your `OnTriggerStay` method, you can extract that information and pass it to the `EquipedItem` method:

```
if (other.gameObject.tag == "Tools")
{
    /*...*/
     if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
     {
         var toolPickup = other.GetComponent<ToolPickup>();
         if(toolPickup != null) 
         {
             EquipedItem(toolPickup.toolIndex);
         }
     }
```

The `EquipedItem` method needs to be modified to take an array index as a parameter and then only change the state of the tool with that array index:

```
public void EquipedItem(int toolIndex)
{
     Items[toolIndex].GetComponent<Rigidbody>().isKinematic = true;
     Items[toolIndex].transform.position = CollectedItems[toolIndex].transform.position;
     Items[toolIndex].transform.rotation = CollectedItems[toolIndex].transform.rotation;
     Items[toolIndex].GetComponent<MeshCollider>().enabled = false;
     Items[toolIndex].transform.SetParent(CollectedItems[toolIndex]);
     ItemImages[toolIndex].enabled = true;

     ItemCllected = true;
 }
```